# Objects relationship (between objects in different collections) in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

> TL/DR: I have two Models each with its own repository, context and controller for MongoDB. How do I build relationships between them similar to how RDBMS would use `ForeignKey` to reference one model from another.

So I have two models, one referencing another one:

```
[Validator(typeof(OrgNameValidator))]
public class Org : BaseEntity
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Portfolio : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
    public Org Organization { get; set; }
}
```

I use MongoDB as backend so each of the two has their own context, repository and controller (*This may be right or wrong, but for the education purposes I am trying to focus on the task of managing relationship between MongoDB documents that is abstracted from the representation at the model/class level*).

My attempt is that when I save a `Portfolio`, at the database level, it will create a document in the `Portfolio` collection that has a field for Org with `ObjectID` referencing a document in the `Org` collection.

So I am trying to POST a new Portfolio:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Portfolio portfolio)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _repository.AddRecord(portfolio);
            return new OkObjectResult(portfolio);
        }
        else
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(BadRequest(ModelState));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(StatusCode(500, ex.Message));
    }
}
```

So there are two scenarios that happen:

1. When passing `Org` `_Id` for `Organization` field (similar with how some other frameworks let you do this) - you end up with invalid input problem: the `Organization` field is `Org` class so it won't validate and I think I am missing some object mapping or something else that potentially comes out of box with AspNetCore.MVC that would allow me to mitigate this.
2. When giving it all `Org` details - will save the Org details inline `Portfolio` document in its own `Portfolio` collection. I assume this is logical since from the object perspective, Org is an Org so it validates the object and nests it into the document - how would it "know" that it needs to save the document in a different collection via a different repository implementation.

I would assume that I could convert things a little to actually be this (having `Organization` be represented as string storing it's _id and then working out the logic of retrieving the relevant data via getters in `Portfolio` class):

```
public class Org : BaseEntity
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Portfolio : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }

    public getOrganization{get{return _repo<Org>.getOrgById(this.Organization)}}
}
```

I am still thinking that there must be something I am missing that will allow me to keep the "conventional" model/class structure similar to how I would have it with RDBMS implementations while having a document-oriented storage at the backend.

Another option here is using MongoDBRef type to reference other documents but it requires a bit of coding to align this to be flexible across modelling entities. I looked for MongoDB repository/entity frameworks implementations and found a few (Yarn, MongoRepository, Simple.Data, SharpRepository) but none are compatible with AspNetCore yet.

What is the pattern in asp.net core that allows me to orchestrate object relationships between different models and objects with MongoDB?

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly then it seems to distil to *"Keep the related data in the object or reference to another collection"*? For which case there is the old adage of *"It's entirely up to the usage pattern required by your application"*. A *"Which is best?"* question is entirely opinion based without very specific details of your usage pattern, and even then possibly too broad.

Comment: As for statements like *"it "understands" that I am referencing another model object"*, then by design this is not the **job** of MongoDB. The whole philosophy is that **your application** is rather responsible for this and not the database itself. This is in fact one of the major distinctions between MongoDB and it's "ilk" and an RDBMS. There are much longer explanations of this you can read, but the most immediate answer is that *"If you are not sure if you should be using MongoDB, then you probably should not", since the point is to cater for where an RDBMS does not suit.

Comment: I have updated my question to be clear around what I am asking, I guess I wasn't specific enough; I am basically trying to figure out if aspnet.core will give me tools to manage some of my needs vs having to manually figure them out (specifically on the relationship thing)